# Can't convert byte to bitarray

Tags: python, collections, bit-manipulation, byte, python-3.5

I want to generate N bytes and then to iterate through bytes and convert every single `byte` to `bitarray`.. but I cant. Questions:

- Why `byte_array` consists of ints and not of bytes?
- Why `byteBitArray`  have None value and how to fix this?

  ```
    import os
    from bitarray import bitarray


    byte_array = bytearray(os.urandom(3))

    for byte in byte_array:
          print (type(byte)) # <class 'int'>, why not byte?
          realByte = byte.to_bytes(1, byteorder='little')
          byteBitArray = a.frombytes(realByte) # byteBitArray = None . Why None?
  ```

Comment: There is no byte object in python.